# Code Behind Gridview's RowDataBound event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have created a gridview in code behind (as in its not physically present on the page). I want to know how to call it's **rowdatabound** event - as data is being bound to it. There happens to be a Gv.RowDataBound function, but how do I use it?

(I want the same functionality as what the asp:gridview control has for its onrowdatabind attribute...)

---

```
GridView Gv = new GridView();
Gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

BoundField one = new BoundField();
one.DataField = "one";
one.HeaderText = "One";
Gv.Columns.Add(one);

BoundField two = new BoundField();
one.DataField = "two";
one.HeaderText = "Two";
Gv.Columns.Add(two);


//dt is a datatable with some data

Gv.DataSource = (dt);
Gv.DataBind();
```

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the eventhandler for the gridview using:

```
 Gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Gv_RowDataBound);
```

Then create its own eventhandler

```
 void Gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do whatever you want in here.
    }
```

Comment: This answer is marked correct but it gave me hard time. At the end I had to prepend the function with `static` keyword which fixed the problem for me. Not sure if it is because of different verions of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in VB, use this:

```
AddHandler Gv.RowDataBound, AddressOf Gv_RowDataBound
```